# How can I "delimit" an integer from a given string?

Tags: java, regex, loops, pattern-matching, delimiter

I am doing an exercise where I must have a string inputted from the keyboard. The string will be simple arithmetic, such as " 2 + 4 + 6 - 8 + 3 - 7". Yes, the format must be like this. Single spaces in between.

The idea is to take this string and eventually print out the answer to it. So far, this is my code:

```
public class AddemUp {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter something like 8 + 33 + 1345 + 137: ");
    String s = kb.nextLine();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(s);
    sc.useDelimiter("\\s*\\+\\s*|\\s*\\-\\s*");
    int sum = 0;
    int theInt;
    Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(s);
    sc1.useDelimiter("\\s*\\s*");
    String plusOrMinus = sc1.next();
    int count = 0;
    if(s.startsWith("-"))
    {
        sum -= sc.nextInt();
    }
    while(sc.hasNextInt())
    {
        theInt = sc.nextInt();
        if(count == 0)
        {
            sum += theInt;
        }
        else if(plusOrMinus.equals("+"))
        {
            sum += theInt;
        }
        else
        {
            sum -= theInt;
        }
        sc1.next();
        count++;
    }
    System.out.println("Sum is: " + sum);
    }
  }
}
```

On line 25, where the "sc1.delimiter" is, I do not know how to have the code skip all of the integers (along with the spaces) and isolate ONLY either the "+" or "-". Once this is achieved, I can simply implement it into the while-loop.

Comment: Use the [shunting-yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm)

Comment: This question may be helpful, as it is trying to *remove* all numbers from a string, which I think you'll find quite similar to using numbers as delimiters https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41505028/java-remove-numbers-from-string

Answer (score 4):

If you want to eliminate the numbers, leaving an array of operands, split on characters *other* than plus or minus:

```
String[] ops = str.split("[^+-]+");
```

fyi, when a minus sign is first or last in a character class it' a literal minus (otherwise it's a range)

Answer (score 2):

Try using `split()` ([JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)) method instead. It is much easier.

```
"8 + 33 + 1345 + 137".split("\\+|\\-")
```

should return an array with numbers.

Comment: I am aware of the split() method, however I do not want to isolate the  numbers in the equation. In fact, I've already done this using the delimiter for Scanner "sc". What I need to isolate are the operator symbols, "+" and "-". I need to ELIMINATE the numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code

```
   "8 + 33 + 1345 + 137".split("(\\s\\d*\\s)|(\\s\\d*)|(\\d*\\s)")
```

here the regular expression checks digit in string along with space before/after/around it.

This splits returns array **[, +, +, +]**

The first place will always be empty unless string starts with +/-, you can access array from [1] position

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use Scanner for this, I would use the pattern matching. They are opposite in that the Scanner wants a delimiter between characters you want, and the pattern matching identifies the characters you want instead.

To find just the operators you could have this...

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[+-]");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("2 + 4 + 6 - 8 + 3 - 7");
    while (m.find()) {
        String token = m.group(0);
        System.out.println(token);
    }
```

The logic can be straight-forward to process when the numbers and operators are together in the loop.  That is why I am including this.

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([^\\s]+)(?:\\s+|$)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("2 + 4 + 6 - 8 + 3 - 7");
    while (m.find()) {
        String token = m.group(1);
        System.out.println(token);
    }
```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/) is a good site for testing regular expressions.

Answer (score -1):

Try this instead:

```
String str = ...
int total = 0;
int operand;
for(int  i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
    if(Character.isWhiteSpace(str.charAt(i)))
    ; // empty
    else if(Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i))){
        StringBuilder number = new StringBuilder();
        while(Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i))){
            number.append(str.charAt(i));
            i++;
        }
        operand = Integer.parseInt(number.toString);
    }
    else if(str.charAt(i)) == '+')
        total += operand;
    else if(str.charAt(i)) == '-)
        total -= operand;
    else
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

Of course you should do a better check, for illegal entries. I just gave you the idea.

Comment: there is many CTE's in your program, like `operand` might not intialized, bracket missing in `number.toString` , `s` should small in `isWhiteSpace` and finnaly output will `IndexOutOfBoundException`

Answer (score -1):

The code below can calculate just sequence of operator '+' and '-' 
I wish it is helpful

```
public class test1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s= "9-15";
    s=s+"/"; /* add / to execute the last operation */
    String split[]= new String[s.length()];
    for (int i=0;i<split.length;i++){   /* split the string to array */
        split[i]=s.substring(i,i+1);
    }
    String val1="",op="+"; /* val1 : container of the value before the operator to calculate it with total
                              op : the operator between val1 and val2 at the begin is + */
    int som=0;
    for (int i=0;i<split.length;i++){
        try{
            val1=val1+Integer.parseInt(split[i]); /* saving the number after the operation in a string to calculate it,
                                                 a number format exception is throwing when the case don't contain integer*/ 
        }catch(NumberFormatException e){
            if(op.equals("+"))  {
                som=som+Integer.parseInt(val1); /*calculate the total */
                val1=""; /*initialize val1 to save the second number */
                op=split[i]; /* save the operator of the next operation */
            }else{
            if(op.equals("-"))  {
                som=som-Integer.parseInt(val1);
                val1="";
                op=split[i];
            }
        }
        }
    } 
    System.out.println(som);
}
}
```

Comment: Answers that just say "here is the solution to your problem" aren't great, because they don't do a great job at helping the OP learn and improve. Besides, it's likely that OP might not *want* someone to hand them a solution, but instead just wants a nudge in the right direction so they can implement the solution themselves.

Answer (score -2):

```
int total = 0;
    final String s = "9 - 15";
    final String[] arr = s.split(" ");
    int i = 0;
    while (i != arr.length)
    {
        switch (arr[i])
        {
            case ("+"):
                total += Integer.parseInt(arr[++i]);
                break;
            case ("-"):
                total -= Integer.parseInt(arr[++i]);
                break;
            case ("*"):
                total *= Integer.parseInt(arr[++i]);
                break;
            case ("/"):
                total /= Integer.parseInt(arr[++i]);
                break;
            default:
                total = Integer.parseInt(arr[i++]);
        }
        if (i == arr.length - 1)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(total);
```

hope this might help you....thnx

Comment: Seems like this will answer 6 + 2 / 2 as 4 instead of 7

Comment: Answers that just say "here is the solution to your problem" aren't great, because they don't do a great job at helping the OP learn and improve. Besides, it's likely that OP might not *want* someone to hand them a solution, but instead just wants a nudge in the right direction so they can implement the solution themselves.

Answer (score -2):

Here you go, hope this helps...

The code you are about to see can solve all basic equations, this means it can solve equations that **only** contain a `.`, `+`, `-`, `*`, and/or `/` symbol in the equation.  This equation can also *add*, *subtract*, *multiple*, and/or *divide* decimals.  This **cannot** solve equations that contains a `x^y`, `(x)`, `[x]`, etc.

```
public static boolean isNum(String e) {
    String[] num=new String[] {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"};
    boolean ret=false;
    for (String n : num) {
        if (e.contains(n)) {
            ret=true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
public static boolean ifMax(String[] e, int i) {
    boolean ret=false;
    if (i == (e.length - 1)) {
        ret=true;
    }
    return ret;
}


public static String getResult(String equation) {
    String[] e=equation.split(" ");
    String[] sign=new String[] {"+", "-", "*", "/"};
    double answer=Double.parseDouble(e[0]);
    for (int i=1; i<e.length; i++) {
        if (isNum(e[i]) != true) {
            if (e[i].equals(sign[0])) {
                double cc=0;
                if (ifMax(e, i) == false) {
                    cc=Double.parseDouble(e[i+1]);
                }
                answer=answer+(cc);
            } else if (e[i].equals(sign[1])) {
                double cc=0;
                if (ifMax(e, i) == false) {
                    cc=Double.parseDouble(e[i+1]);
                }
                answer=answer-(cc);
            } else if (e[i].equals(sign[2])) {
                if (ifMax(e, i) == false) {
                   answer=answer*(Double.parseDouble(e[i+1]));
                }
            } else if (e[i].equals(sign[3])) {
                if (ifMax(e, i) == false) {
                   answer=answer/(Double.parseDouble(e[i+1]));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return equation+" = "+answer;
}
```

And here is an example of it:

**Input:**

```
System.out.println(getResult("1 + 2 + 3 + 4 / 2 - 3 * 6"));
```

**Output:**

```
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 / 2 - 3 * 6 = 12
```

Comment: Answers that just say "here is the solution to your problem" aren't great, because they don't do a great job at helping the OP learn and improve. Besides, it's likely that OP might not *want* someone to hand them a solution, but instead just wants a nudge in the right direction so they can implement the solution themselves.