# Java: Remove numbers from string

Tags: java, regex, string, replaceall

I have a string like `23.Piano+trompet`, and i wanted to remove the `23.` part from the string using this function:

```
private String removeSignsFromName(String name) {
    name = name.replaceAll(" ", "");
    name = name.replaceAll(".", "");

    return name.replaceAll("\\^([0-9]+)", "");
}
```

But it doesn't do it. Also, there is no error in runtime.

Comment: You escape the `^`, so it searches for a literal `^`, which is not present.

Comment: `.` matches any character and `replaceAll()` replaces all the characters. Escape the dot `"\\."`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following replaces all whitespace characters (`\\s`), dots (`\\.`), and digits (`\\d`) with `""`:

```
name.replaceAll("^[\\s\\.\\d]+", "");
```

> what if I want to replace the `+` with `_`?

```
name.replaceAll("^[\\s\\.\\d]+", "").replaceAll("\\+", "_");
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to escape the `^`, you can use `\\d+` to match multiple digits, and `\\.` for a literal dot and you don't need multiple calls to `replaceAll`. For example,

```
private static String removeSignsFromName(String name) {
    return name.replaceAll("^\\d+\\.", "");
}
```

Which I tested like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(removeSignsFromName("23.Piano+trompet"));
}
```

And got

```
Piano+trompet
```

Comment: he needs the `^`, if he want to make sure the replacement can only occur on the beginning of string.  however he should not escape the `^` Your pattern will replace all `number + dot`s in the text, don't know if it is desired. Also, what for the grouping, it makes no sense, does it?

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

1. The . in the second replaceAll should be escaped:

   ```
   name=name.replaceAll("\\.", "");
   ```
2. The ^ in the third one should NOT be escaped:

   ```
   return name.replaceAll("^([0-9]+)", "");
   ```

Oh! and the parentheses are useless since you don't use the captured string.

Answer (score 1):

How about this：

```
public static String removeNumOfStr(String str) {
    if (str == null) {
        return null;
    }
    char[] ch = str.toCharArray();
    int length = ch.length;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int i = 0;
    while (i < length) {
        if (Character.isDigit(ch[i])) {
            i++;
        } else {
            sb.append(ch[i]);
            i++;
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return name.replaceFirst("^\\d+\\.", "");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void removenum(String str){

    char[] arr=str.toCharArray();
    String s="";

    for(char ch:arr){

        if(!(ch>47 & ch<57)){

            s=s+ch;
        }
            }
    System.out.println(s);

}
```